# My code VHDL compiles,but I don't get the expected result in the wave simulation

Tags: vhdl

This can be done with sentences while,if, etc. But it is necessary to do it with the equation of the state table.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


entity P_4 is
           port (CK: IN std_logic;  
           S1,S0: out std_logic);
end P_4;

architecture ASINC of P_4 is  

signal y0:std_logic;
signal y2:std_logic;
signal y1:std_logic;

begin
    y0<=(not(ck) and y0) or (ck and y2 and y1) or (ck and not(y2) and not(y1));
    y1<=(ck and y1) or (y1 and not(y0)) or (not(ck) and not(y2) and y0) or (not(y2) and y1 and y0) or (not(ck) and not(y2)and y1);
    y2<=(ck and y2) or (y2 and y0) or (not(ck) and y1 and y0);
    s0<=(not(ck) and y0) or (ck and y2 and not(y1)) or (ck and not (y2) and y1);
    s1<= (ck and y2) or (y2 and y0) or ((not(ck) and y1 and not(y0)));

END ASINC;
```

[image: The wave simulation isn´t expected]

**A try:**

I tried this, but I don't get result, the output image is the same as the one above. The code compiles without errors.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


entity P_4 is
           port (
              CK: IN std_logic:='0';  
           S1,S0: out std_logic
              );
end P_4;

architecture ASINC of P_4 is  

    signal y0:std_logic:='0';
    signal y2:std_logic:='0';
    signal y1:std_logic:='0';
    signal k0:std_logic;
    signal k2:std_logic;
    signal k1:std_logic;

begin
    k0<=(not(ck) and y0) or (ck and y2 and y1) or (ck and not(y2) and not(y1));
    k1<=(ck and y1) or (y1 and not(y0)) or (not(ck) and not(y2) and y0) or (not(y2) and y1 and y0) or (not(ck) and not(y2)and y1);
    k2<=(ck and y2) or (y2 and y0) or (not(ck) and y1 and y0);
    y0<=k0;
    y1<=k1;
    y2<=k2;
    s0<=(not(ck) and y0) or (ck and y2 and not(y1)) or (ck and not (y2) and y1);
    s1<= (ck and y2) or (y2 and y0) or ((not(ck) and y1 and not(y0)));

END ASINC;
```

Comment: The 'X's are caused by combinatorial feedback with the values of y0, y1 and y2 uninitialized and contributing to their own value assignments. See the and_table and not_table in the VHDL source for the std_logic_1164 package body.

Comment: thanks,, @user1155120 , how i can to do that?

Comment: If you provide initial values where y0, y2 and y1 are declared you're simulation will produce waveforms consisting of '1' and '0' values. Note y1 won't change, and the patterns exhibited on y0, y2 , s0 and s1 are dependent on the initial values ([try '0' as the initial value on all three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnnFs.jpg)). What is p_4 anyway?

Comment: thanks @user1155120,,,. Is Problem 4 ---> P_4

Comment: @user1155120 but, how do I initialize it? Either in the code or in the simulation, please. I've been days without sleep.xD

Comment: The declaration can be supplied with an initial value like so:   signal y0:std_logic := '0';

Answer (score 0):

y0/1/2 Are all initialised to 'U' (uninitialised) because you didnt provide an initial value. Hence your boolean expressions will all output 'U'. In your simulator this appears to be coming out as X (Unknown).

Comment: thanks @Tricky ,,yes i know, but  how i can to do that?.I tried with `:='0' `..but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing y0/1/2 is not enough. If you are using a TB, make sure that the signal connected to CK is initialized. Otherwise,

```
entity P_4 is
  port (
    CK: IN std_logic:='0';  
    S1,S0: out std_logic
);
end P_4;
```

Note that you need to initialize y0/1/2 as well as CK.